# how to resolve overlapping labels on x-axis (highcharts)

Tags: highcharts

I am using the highcharts library.
I have set the xaxis as a datetime axis.

I am in a situation where the ticks on x-axis are overlapping.

http://jsfiddle.net/owge98Lm/

Setting "tickPixelInterval" didn't help:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: { rotation: 45 },
    tickPixelInterval: 50
  },
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `tickPositions` are very far apart you can use [zooming](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/zooming)  and add `chart: { type: 'areaspline', zoomType: 'x' },`

Comment: I am sure you can do many things with overlapping labels, but what do you want them to look like? Should one of them be hidden?

Comment: @morganfree .. i simply don't want them to overlap. They should be visible next to each other

Comment: You can move them - to the right/left, both/one - you can do it on load event and optionally on redraw -http://jsfiddle.net/owge98Lm/1/